# MVC Routing Null parameters error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my `Index` page I have the following link to the `Details` view:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ClubId })|
```

My controller is expecting an int:

```
public ActionResult Details(int ClubId)
{
    var club = _service.GetClub(ClubId);
    var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClubViewModel>(club);
    return View(model);
}
```

Im getting this every time though:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ClubId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in
>   'MyProject.Web.Controllers.ClubsController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I know this is something to do with routing however I have tried swapping `UrlParameter.Optional` to `""` and making the ViewModel's ClubId nullable but the error remains.

If I rewire my controller to accept a `Club` object and pass in `item` from the Index view then everything is fine and the `ClubId` is populated in debug but I'm left with a stupidly large parameter list in the URL.

I don't really get what the problem is here?

Comment: have you tried using ClubId instead of just id?

Comment: For gods sake, thanks

Comment: There is a difference between `/url/parameters` and `?query=string&parameters`. The former affects the routing, the latter does not.

Comment: would you mind marking mine as the answer? Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using ClubId instead of just id?

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is expecting a parameter named `ClubId` but you're passing a parameter called `id`. They need to match.

Comment: Sometimes I've experienced a weird issue with `id` parameter name not working at all, that is parameter was not populated when the action was called. So these should better match as `ClubId`